# passing collection from constructor to controller action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to pass a list of products ( which is being created in controller's constructor) to action method of controller. How can I pass it to controller action and then further to view ?

I am doing like this:

```
 public ProductsController()
        {
            var products = new List<Product> {
                new Product {Id=1,Name="Milk",Price=1.99m},
                new Product {Id=1,Name="Bread",Price=3.00m},
                new Product {Id=1,Name="Steak",Price=12.00m}
            };
        }
```

How can I access this collection in action method ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: Make a field and assign that collection to field and read it in action

Comment: @Jani: Do you mean creating a property or what ? Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Constructor -> Action Method:

Declare an instance field or property on your controller class and assign the list to it. Then every action method in the controller will be able to access it.

For Action Method -> View:

Either create a strongly-typed model class that has a field that can store your collection or simply pass it into the view using `ViewData`/`ViewBag`.